# Compact cohomology group of connected n-dimensional connected oriented manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I know how to show $H_c^n(M)\simeq\mathbb{R}$, where M is a oriented connected n-dimensional manifold, by showing the integration map is isomorphism. However, I found in the book that this is a consequence of Poincaré duality. I don't know how to deduce this result from that theorem. Can any one help?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what version of Poincare duality you've learnt, but the following version of Poincare duality is quit standard, I think:

If $M$ is as you said, then the cap product with the fundamental class $\cap [M]$ is an isomorphism between $H^k_c(M)$ and $H_{n-k}(M)$.

Then the isomorphism follows trivially by $H_0(M)=\mathbb{R}^{\mathrm{number\;of\;connected\;components}}\cong \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note as the OP refered to $H^k_c$, the OP likely meant compactly supported de Rham cohomology (which is of course isomorphic to singular cohomology where the cap product makes sense but one needs to do work to see this).

Comment: @PVAL You are right. The Poincare duality I learnt is with the same requirement in the problem, $H^q(M)\simeq (H_c^{n-q}(M))^*$, which means De Rham Cohomology and dual space of compact cohomology.

Comment: PVAL // Indeed. Maybe OP would need de Rham's theorem to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

It's a special case.

In the cohomology form of Poincare duality defines a homeomorphism:
$$H_c^n(M) \simeq H^0(M)$$
In fact the cup product is just the integration map you mentioned
$$H_c^n(M) \times H^0(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}:\ (\omega, f) \rightarrow \int_Mf\cdot\omega$$

Now $H^0(M) = \mathbb{R}$ as any closed 0-form (functions with derivative 0) are just constants on any connected $M.$